# How to send dispatchTouchEvent() from service to any Underlay Activity

Tags: events, touch, handle

**WHAT I WANT TO DO?**
- Basically i want to do the human touch pragmatically at specific time at specific X,Y Coordinates
- Run a service which will receive the X,Y coordinates via some interface (TCP/UDP)
- fire dispatchTouchEvent() using those coordinates and get the results as actual human finger click gives
- I mean focussed activity might be anything either it is Android Home Screen OR Any opened activity OR Anything
- The moment service invokes the dispatchTouchEvent(), It should perform the click. 
- For example if opened App is calculator and X,Y coordinates of dispatchTouchEvent() points to numeric 5, It should press the 5 key

**WHAT I HAVE DONE TILL NOW?**
- I have started a service which receives X,Y coordinates
- On some trigger, it invokes the dispatchTouchEvent(), but it does not work. It does not click anything on the screen.
- It capture every touch event made by human finger.

**WHATS THE ISSUE?**
- How to issue dispatchTouchEvent() to any underlay activity

**SAMPLE CODE:**
i am attaching the sample code here. I have just made it simple for test purpose.
First we need to click anywhere in the screen. Its X,Y coordinates will be saved and after some time dispatchTouchEvent() will be invoked
using same coordinates.

*MainActivity.java*

```
package com.test.overlay;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //Intent intent = new Intent(this, Overlay.class);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, PlayerServiceTest.class);
        startService(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

*Overlay.java*

```
package com.test.overlay;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class Overlay extends Service 
{
    HUDView mView;


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"onCreate", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        mView = new HUDView(this);

        /*
        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
                //WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LOCAL_FOCUS_MODE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
                //WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);    
        */


        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);


        /*
        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
                0,
                //WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        */
        params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.TOP;
        params.setTitle("Load Average");
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        wm.addView(mView, params);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"onDestroy", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if(mView != null)
        {
            ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).removeView(mView);
            mView = null;
        }
    }
}

class HUDView extends ViewGroup 
{
    private Paint mLoadPaint;

    public HUDView(Context context) 
    {
        super(context);
        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"HUDView", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        mLoadPaint = new Paint();
        mLoadPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        //mLoadPaint.setTextSize(10);
        mLoadPaint.setTextSize(25);
        //mLoadPaint.setTypeface(Typeface.SANS_SERIF);
        mLoadPaint.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
        mLoadPaint.setARGB(255, 25, 200, 50);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
    {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawText("THIS IS TEST", 15, 115, mLoadPaint); 
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3, int arg4) 
    {
        System.out.println("onLayout called ...");
        //handleAutoTouches();
    }

  //===============================================================================
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public void TestThread()
    {
          AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {            
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() 
            {
                //System.out.println("post0...");
            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) 
            {   
                //System.out.println("Time started-1");
                try 
                {       
                    //if(flag != 0)
                    Thread.sleep(7*1000);                       

                } 
                catch (InterruptedException e) 
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) 
            {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //System.out.println("handleAutoTouches called-2");
                handleAutoTouches();
            }           
        };
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
            task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, (Void[])null);
        else
            task.execute((Void[])null);
    }
    //=======================================================================================

    public void handleAutoTouches()
    {       
        long downTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        //long eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + 100;
        long eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis()+700;

        //float x = 71.0f;
        //float y = 138.0f;

        //float x = 120.0f;
        //float y = 170.0f;

        //Set Manual x/y co-rdinates here
        float x = xCor;
        float y = yCor;
        boolean val;

        // List of meta states found here:     developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#getMetaState()
        int metaState = 0;
        final MotionEvent motionEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(
            downTime, 
            eventTime, 
            //MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, 
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN,
            x, 
            y, 
            metaState
        );  
        System.out.println("CLICKED DOWN...");
        val = super.dispatchTouchEvent(motionEvent);
        System.out.println("Status:"+val);


        final MotionEvent motionEvent1 = MotionEvent.obtain(
                downTime, 
                eventTime, 
                //MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, 
                MotionEvent.ACTION_UP,
                x, 
                y, 
                metaState
        );              
        System.out.println("CLICKED UP...");
        val = super.dispatchTouchEvent(motionEvent1);
        System.out.println("Status:"+val);
        //-------------------------------------------------------

        flag=0;
    }

    int flag=0;
    float xCor=0;
    float yCor=0;


    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) 
    {         
        //System.out.println("flag:"+flag);
        if(flag == 0) //When manual touch was done
        {
            //Set flag to avoid the looping
            flag=1;

            //Get the manual touch co-ordinates for Auto Touch next time
            xCor=event.getRawX();
            yCor=event.getRawY();

            TestThread();
        }       
        System.out.println("onTouchEvent,"+"X:"+event.getRawX()+", Y:"+event.getRawY());  
        return true;
        //return false;
    }


    /*
     @Override
     public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
     {
        System.out.println("intercepted..."); 
        System.out.println("onTouchEvent,"+"X:"+event.getRawX()+", Y:"+event.getRawY());

        if(flag == 0) //When manual touch was done
        {
            //Set flag to avoid the looping
            flag=1;

            //Get the manual touch co-ordinates for Auto Touch next time
            xCor=event.getRawX();
            yCor=event.getRawY();

            TestThread();
        }

        onTouchEvent(event);
        return false;
     }*/

}
```

Please point me to the right direction.

Comment: there are some posts on SO about using transparent activity, with flag_not_touchable, then the touch will touch through to the underlying activity. However, if using this flag, I guess you cannot capture the touch.  In fact, I also want to know the solution to your question, did you solved it? I am having the same problem, but I am using a service and show a chathead, the chathead can capture the touch event, but I cannot figure out how to send the touch to underlying activity.

Comment: Same page here, did you every find a solution for it?